# PHP Parse error on gulp default for mibew live chat

Tags: php, node.js, gulp, livechat

everybody! I installed mibew ver. 2.2.2 (it works well) and want to make changes in it (add and build new "style"). OS - windows 10. So, I also installed tools for building sources:

1. [cmd] node -v =>v**8.1.3**
2. [cmd] npm -v =>v**5.0.4**
3. [cmd] gulp -v => CLI version **1.3.0** Local version **3.9.1**
4. [cmd] php -r "echo phpversion();" =>**5.4.35**

Then, I donwloaded [source-archive](https://github.com/Mibew/mibew) and follow the [instructions](https://docs.mibew.org/development/build-system.html).
As a result I got this:

```
D:\www\home\mibew\loc\src>gulp default
[16:52:05] Using gulpfile D:\www\home\mibew\loc\src\gulpfile.js
[16:52:05] Starting 'default'...
[16:52:05] Starting 'clean'...
[16:52:05] Finished 'clean' after 127 ms
[16:52:05] Starting 'js'...
[16:52:05] Starting 'chat-styles-handlebars'...
[16:52:05] Starting 'chat-styles-js'...
[16:52:05] Starting 'page-styles'...
[16:52:05] Finished 'chat-styles-js' after 276 ms
[16:52:06] Finished 'page-styles' after 801 ms
[16:52:07] Finished 'chat-styles-handlebars' after 1.41 s
[16:52:07] Starting 'chat-styles'...
[16:52:07] Finished 'chat-styles' after 51 μs
[16:52:07] Finished 'js' after 2.04 s
[16:52:07] Starting 'get-composer'...
[16:52:07] Starting 'bower-install'...
[16:52:08] 'get-composer' errored after 794 ms
[16:52:08] Error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in - on line 1472

    at formatError (C:\Users\Nika\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^3.7.0\formatError.js:20:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Nika\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^3.7.0\log\events.js:41:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (D:\www\home\mibew\loc\src\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at D:\www\home\mibew\loc\src\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (D:\www\home\mibew\loc\src\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at cb (D:\www\home\mibew\loc\src\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:29:3)
    at D:\www\home\mibew\loc\src\gulpfile.js:108:13
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:277:5)
[16:52:08] 'default' errored after 2.96 s
[16:52:08] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(get-composer)'
Error
    at finish (D:\www\home\mibew\loc\src\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:56:13)
    at Gulp.onError (D:\www\home\mibew\loc\src\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:67:4)
    at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (D:\www\home\mibew\loc\src\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at D:\www\home\mibew\loc\src\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (D:\www\home\mibew\loc\src\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at cb (D:\www\home\mibew\loc\src\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:29:3)
    at D:\www\home\mibew\loc\src\gulpfile.js:108:13
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:277:5)
[16:52:12] Finished 'bower-install' after 5.05 s
```

Please tell me, what causes an error? What is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After some time beating against the wall I analyzed the file **gulpfile.js** and put the file **composer.phar** in the same directory and strated again with "gulp default" from command line and... miracle! It done without errors and I found in folder *release* .zip and .tar.gz archives.

Comment: please tell me, where this **compose.phar** file is placed.

Comment: now i figure out, i already installed composer in my system, so i go to that directory and copy **composer.phar** file, and place it on **mibew/src** folder.